# Format() not working in Visual Basic (Visual Studio 2005/ Win 7)

Tags: vb.net, datetime, formatting

I am having a problem with Format not working. I have tried several standard formats but it doesn't effect the output at all.

Dim tempstring As String = Format(Now(), "M, m")
and 
Dim date As Date = Format(Now(), "M, m")

both have a final value of "8/16/2010 10:52:21 AM"

Thanks for the help.

**Update**
I am still having problems in my program.  I have tried format in a test console app and it works fine, so the problem is not vb or vs.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim date As Date = Format(Now(), "M, m")
```

This will never keep a format, as you're putting a string into a date value (I haven't tried it, but I'd be surprised if it didn't throw an error)

```
Dim tempstring As String = Format(Now(), "M, m")
```

This works a treat for me, giving "8, 2" (M-month, m-minute)

**Update**
My full test code,

```
Dim tempstring As String = Format(Now(), "M, m")
Console.WriteLine(tempstring)

Console.WriteLine("Press any key")
Console.ReadKey()
```

gives (when run in august, and 2 minutes past the hour)

```
8, 2   
Press any key
```

Comment: I didn't think date as date would work, but tried it anyway.  I can't get 

Dim tempstring As String = Format(Now(), "M, m")

to work.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Casey Haralson: By "not work", what exactly do you mean? What result do you get? Also, can you put this part in a console app and get it to fail? I don't think the format is your problem, there's something going wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, I tried it in a console app and format worked perfectly.  In my regular app the output of the format is "8/16/2010 10:52:21 AM".  Another thing I noticed is that putting the output of the format into a variable as date type does not throw an error.

Comment: @Casey: Dude, your problem isn't with the format, there's something else going wrong mate. You need to identify what that is.

Comment: Sure, I understand that.  I have figured out a work around to my problem (.ToString(formating stuff here) worked for me).  Thanks for the help.